# Can you call a template file without assigning template to a page in the admin panel?

Tags: page-template

This idea is just to protect certain sections of my theme from over-zealous clients. I would like to add pages, that exist in the front end and can be added to the menu (using wordpress 3.0 api) but the page NOT be present in the 'Pages' dialogue in the admin panel, and is thus not user editable.

Comment: This question is a little bit vague. Could you clarify please?

Comment: What I mean, I want to call a template file without assigning that you a page.

Comment: For example, I have a section that lists venues. It is a loop based on the custom post type, 'Venus'. I have a template file with that loop, but in order to put that page in the navigation, I have to assign the template to a page. Can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook into template_redirect like this:

```
function custom_template_redirect() {
    global $wp;

    if ($wp->query_vars['pagename'] == 'my-page-slug') { // check the page slug
        status_header(200); // a 404 code will not be returned in the HTTP headers if the page does not exists

        include(TEMPLATEPATH . "/test.php"); // include the corresponding template
        die();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_template_redirect' );
```

Comment: Does this mean I still need to have a page in the pages DB in order to have a nav link?

Comment: Yes, you will need to have the page in the db, or you can hook into the filter 'wp_nav_menu_items' or "wp_nav_menu_{$menu->slug}_items"  with a custom code to add the page in the nav.